# Socket.Bind and IP source routing, with multiple local network interfaces

Tags: windows, sockets, routes, tcp

I wrote a tool running on a system (Win7) with two network interfaces, each linked to a different subnet, each with its own gateway which is then linked to two separate distant networks (there are outgoing firewalls after each gateway). I’m initiating outgoing TCP connections via both NICs by using `Socket.Bind` (before doing `Connect`) to each relevant NIC’s IP address. First NIC is working fine, but for the second NIC, I’m getting `SocketException`: *“A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network”*.

My original understanding was that since sockets are bound to concrete NIC’s local endpoint, which has its gateway defined, the connection should be routed to this gateway and therefore should work. However, it seems that source IP address is ignored and the routing is working according to local routing table (i.e. second NIC’s connect request goes to first, default, network and being rejected because it has wrong subnet).

Adjusting local routing tables helps, but it makes me wonder about the whole reasoning behind ability of the socket to bind to specific local IP.

Doing some extra reading, I found out that, indeed, there’s such thing as “source IP routing”, but it is disabled in Windows by default (via `DisableIPSourceRouting` registry setting), due to security reasons, as described, e.g. here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648853.aspx
- http://www.bloggersbase.com/disableipsourcerouting/

**Questions:**

1. If my original understanding was correct (i.e. `Socket.Bind` should be enough) – why it is not working without modifying routing tables?
2. If my understand was NOT correct (i.e. `Socket.Bind` is ignored and routing is used) – what’s the point of having Socket.Bind? Why doing it at all?
3. Also, I’d like to understand better, what is the actual risk of having source IP routing enabled (preferably with example of a possible exploit)?
4. Any ideas of solving the requirement without manually modifying local routing table will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Binding a socket to an interface is not "source routing", Source routing means the sender decides which routers the packet should go through, it's usage (LSRR, SSRR) is blocked on the internet. What you are looking for is "source based routing" where not only the destination address determines where should a packet go, but the source address too. This is important to set up when you want to forward incoming connections on a VPN for example: you want the response packets to go through VPN instead of your default internet gateway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, after some reading, here are some high-level explanations on what's happening. I still need to verify the below conclusions in my system. Apparently, local binding is typically ignored when selecting network interface. Instead, routing table is used for this. However, in **Strong Host Model** (default for Vista and newer, non-existant in XP), source IP **is** used as a 'constraint' in the routing table lookup.

- Brief explanation about strong host model vs. weak host model:
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.09.cableguy.aspx
- Explanation on what's different in XP vs newer Windows versions in respect to the above:
  [http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/04/24/source-ip-address-selection-on-a-multi-homed-windows-computer.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150228141804/http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/04/24/source-ip-address-selection-on-a-multi-homed-windows-computer.aspx)